# Updating Excel Fields by OLEDB Deletes Defined Cell Names

Tags: c#, excel, oledb, ms-jet-ace

I'm using OLEDB to update an excel file, this is the example of one of my updates that I have trouble :

```
OleDbConnection myConnection;
OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand();

myConnection = new OleDbConnection(
     "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\my_template.xslm; Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=No;\""
);
myConnection.Open();
myCommand.Connection = myConnection;

string sql = "Update [Sheet1$D16:D16] SET F1 = 'Some Text Here'"; 
myCommand.CommandText = sql;
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

That update works fine, updates the cell I want. But, It also updates the previously defined cell name. That cell names used in formulas. 
You can see the problem at that image :

[image]

Anyone faced that issue before ?

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good answer but if you're under pressue... you could check how the Name is Defined - is it local to the Sheet or Global and then test whether it still fails using the alternative...

Next you could check whether the driver has a fault... i.e. did it work ok before - has something changed